# pip and virtualenv (w/o virtualenvwrapper): pip install package_name gives permission denied but using sudo installs globally

Tags: python, linux, installation, virtualenv

I have the `neurolab` package version `0.2.0` in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`. 
Now I would like to install `neurolab` version `0.1.0` in a virtual environment.

This is after installing pip and virtualenv:

```
~$ mkdir neuro_env
~$ cd neuro_env
~/neuro_env$ virtualenv envi
~/neuro_env$ source envi/bin/activate
(envi)~/neuro_env$ pip install neurolab==0.1.0
```

Then the install fails, with at the end of the error the line:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/username/.pip/pip.log'
```

But when I install it with permissions like this:

```
(envi)~/neuro_env$ sudo pip install neurolab==0.1.0
```

Then version `0.1.0` is just installed globally again (in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`)

I read I could use the -E flag, but that is not possible anymore it seems: 
`error: no such option: -E`

So how do I install `neurolab` version `0.1.0` only for my project in`~/neuro_env`?

### Edit

```
(envi)~/neuro_env$ ls -l /home/username/.pip
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 874 2012-07-28 13:18 pip.log
```

Comment: It looks like `/home/username/.pip/pip.log` is owned by root or has the wrong permissions (or it doesn't exist yet, but `/home/username/.pip` has similar problems). Can you add the output of `ls -l /home/username/.pip` to your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `/home/username/.pip/pip.log` file is only writable by root, so when you try to use `pip` as another user you don't have permission to update the log file and the whole operation fails.

Changing the ownership of the log file (using `sudo chown username:username /home/username/.pip/pip.log`) or removing it (using `sudo rm /home/username/.pip/pip.log`) should fix your problem.

Comment: Thnx! Strange that my .pip/pip.log has these permissions by default.

Comment: If the log file was created when you were using `sudo pip …` that would probably explain the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows. type in powershell or terminal:

```
python -m pip install WHATEVER
```