# sudo virtualenv -p gives PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied?

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv

When I try to run

```
sudo virtualenv -p /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS
```

It shows the following error:

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/virtualenv", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.8.2', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 897, in main
    popen = subprocess.Popen([interpreter, file] + sys.argv[1:], env=env)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/subprocess.py", line 818, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/subprocess.py", line 1416, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I tried removing my pip.log file as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708708/pip-and-virtualenv-w-o-virtualenvwrapper-pip-install-package-name-gives-permi) advised me to, but the problem persists. Any solutions?

Edit:

I should explain that I'm trying to create a virtualenv located at the `<path name>` because I want to install a package with pip for that version of Python.

Comment: Your `Versions/7.3/` tree seems to be tangled up with your `3.3` tree. It *feels* to me as if there is something rather messed up about your setup.

Comment: Then this might be "too localized"- to delete or not...

Comment: Ah, no, your virtualenv script is the 3.3 version, not anything associated with your 7.3 tree. Wrong virtualenv script, I suspect.