# matplotlib imported but pyplot cannot be imported

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two pythons in my mac, they are python 3.4 and 2.7
I can import matplotlib in python 3.4 but as I run

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib import pyplot
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.dev1-py3.4-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 29, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.dev1-py3.4-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 34, in <module>
    import matplotlib.collections as collections
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.dev1-py3.4-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/matplotlib/collections.py", line 27, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backend_bases as backend_bases
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.dev1-py3.4-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 62, in <module>
    import matplotlib.textpath as textpath
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.dev1-py3.4-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/matplotlib/textpath.py", line 18, in <module>
    from matplotlib.mathtext import MathTextParser
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.dev1-py3.4-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/matplotlib/mathtext.py", line 63, in <module>
    import matplotlib._png as _png
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.dev1-py3.4-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/matplotlib/_png.so, 2): Library not loaded: libpng15.15.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.dev1-py3.4-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/matplotlib/_png.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I am beginner. Can anybody help me figure out what is going on and what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem.

> Library not loaded: libpng15.15.dylib

Use this sequence of commands to get to where you want.

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
rm -rf /tmp/pip-build-root/
brew update
brew install libpng --universal
brew install freetype --universal
pip install matplotlib

(venv)  venv ~ python 
Python 3.4.3 (default, Mar 23 2015, 04:19:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot
>>>
```

Comment: I cannot run the pip3 uninstall matplotlib due to this error:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.dev1-py3.4-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/__pycache__/pylab.cpython-34.pyc'

Comment: Hey @Elham! I unfortunelty can't recreate this error above. Can you read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708708/pip-and-virtualenv-w-o-virtualenvwrapper-pip-install-package-name-gives-permi or try `pyvenv venv && cd venv && source bin/activate && pip install matplotlib` and see if that works in a virtualenv?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution to the issue that worked for me:

1- in terminal type  `$open -a Finder /usr`

2- right click on local and do get info

3- unlock the lock at the bottom

4- click + sign and add your user to the list and give read/write privileges

5- click on the gear sign at the bottom and choose apply to enclosed items to recurse under that directory and assign privileges too all directories beneath it.